# Npm dependency issue: react 17.0.2 and "react-swipeable-views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install

I'm trying to add `react-swipeable-views` library to my Project, but I get the following error:

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: e-ecom@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-swipeable-views@0.14.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react-swipeable-views
    npm ERR!   react-swipeable-views@"0.14.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It is because the package you are trying to use is not compatible with React 18, React-Swipeable-Views package looks to be not maintained any more, but someone has posted a forked fix version where you can get at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable-views-react-18-fix to use at your own risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add --legacy-peer-deps OR --force at the end of the install command as mentioned in the error you got

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).